# Is there a way to do several findById operations for a given array of _ids?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, outer-join

I am using mongoose to interact with a mongo database via a React frontend.

I would like to allow a user to input a list of _ids and return the associated entries.  Before they are returned, I would like to get the author for each one and make sure they're allowed to see it. (Eventually I will check if the returned author for each object isn't the currently logged in user, then return 403 forbidden.)

Some _ids provided may not exist in the database, but I still want to know that an entry with that id does not exist rather than return nothing.  It seems that with every method I have tried, Mongo will just omit if it doesn't find a match.

For example, if I use:

```
model.find({ '_id': {$in: {*bad_IDvalue1*, *bad_IDvalue2*, *good_IDvalue*}})
```

I get an array with a single entry.  I would rather get an array with two "bad" or null entries that are missing a value in the valuable author field, and 1 good one that has an actual author.

My first thought was to use an outer forEach loop and a findByID in each loop.  Then I could check if `(!result)` and if false, I would know about it and could error out.  Then I could verify they are the author and have permission to see it.  If all is good, pop the entry onto an array and return to the frontend.  But forEach causes weird async problems where the array I'll push things to gets returned before I finish my findByID calls.  I think there must be a better way.

In SQL I could have done an outer join.  I would take my original input array and outer join it with a table.  The returned table would have a bunch of blank fields in the rows of the inputted invalid _ids.

I am thinking that .populate may help me here but I cannot figure it out.

Here is something I tried that didnt work:

```
Card.find({ '_id': { $in: cardIDList }}) //should I use populate instead????
        .then(resCards => {console.log(JSON.stringify(resCards))})  //resCards can be EMPTY if they are all bogus IDs
        .then(resCards => {
            resCards.forEach(resCard => {
                if (!resCard) {  //doesn't work.  Because the returned array doesn't contain a "null" entry
                    console.log("no card")
                    cardIDerrors = true;
                }
                if (resCard.author != req.user.id) {
                    console.log("forbidden")
                    cardIDerrors = true;
                }
            });
        })
...
```

Comment: *" in SQL I  would..."* - basically **insert bad programming habit here**. SQL lets you get away with **a lot**, and mostly a lot of things you really should not be doing for instance. Instead of looking for *"multiple queries"* or *"outer joins*". Instead just  `let results = cardIDList.map((e,i) => resCards,find(c => ObjectId(e).equals(c._id)))`. Which will work through the original array with `Array.map()` and use `Array.find()` to either return the matching element or `undefined` for each array element of the original array. Hence, every item you searched for in original order with "gaps".

Comment: For `null` you can basically do `.then( resCards => cardIDList.map((e,i) => (resCards.find(c => ObjectId(e).equals(c._id)) == undefined) ? null : resCards.find(c => ObjectId(e).equals(c._id))) )`. Don't `JSON.stringify`, because that's just the wrong approach.

Comment: Actually just: `.then( resCards => cardIDList.map(e => resCards.find(c => ObjectId(e).equals(c._id)) || null )` really, which is about as short as it needs to get.

Comment: @NeilLunn I've tried to implement what you describe in your first comment.  I think I am missing something:
- first I changed `resCards,find` to `resCards.find` 
- then I realized resCards doesn't apply here - I think it should actually be `Card.find`  since Card is the name of my model
- now I am getting a "ObjectId is not defined" error.  

I will work through it a bit more

Comment: Got it now.  I misunderstood.  You were saying to do the find, search the resulting array for matches, map them back onto the original ID list.  the `resCards.find` was an array find, not a mongoose find.  I have what I need now, returning an array of either matches or undefineds.  Thanks!

Comment: It can be a little tricky, but yes everything I showed were "array operators" working on the result from the `Model.find()` from the database which returns the array. And of course the source array used for the `$in` argument.

Comment: Also for reference my standard import from mongoose typically goes like `const { Schema: { Types: { ObjectId } } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');` as those are basically the *constants* that typically get more use. Notably `ObjectId`, because even with mongoose autocasting, things like the `equals()` as shown above still come up regularly enough.